# A simple proof that all the symmetries of the Dirichlet energy are conformal

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, symmetry

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403900/all-the-symmetries-of-the-dirichlet-energy-are-conformal).

It seems to be folklore knowledge that all the (source) symmetries of the $d$-Dirichlet energy are conformal maps.

Specifically, I have found [this nice proof](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjasKK1ie7VAhWL7YMKHabbDsMQFggsMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fddg.math.uni-goettingen.de%2Fpub%2FCMpDE.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHuijFJek6FTzpt0AmLRrfNu8OhmQ) for the following claim:

> **Proposition:** Let $M,N$ be oriented $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, let $f:M \to N$ be a (local) diffeomorphism. Suppose that for any $h \in C^{\infty}(N)$, $$ E_N^p(h)=E_M^p(h \circ f)$$
>   where $E^p$ is the $p$-energy: $E_N^p(h)=\int_N \|dh\|^p \operatorname{Vol}_N$. (we assume $p\ge 1$).
>
> Then,
>
> If $p \neq n$, $\,f$ is an isometry. If $p = n, \,f$ is conformal.

**Question:** **Are there any other proofs around?**

While the proof I mentioned is nice, there are some "magical choices" involved, and I wonder if there is a simpler proof (with less computations).

The challenge is to pass "from global to local"; Here is a naive approach:

Suppose $f:M \to N$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism:

We assume
$$\int_M \|dh \circ df\|^p \operatorname{Vol}_M=\int_N \|dh\|^p \operatorname{Vol}_N=\int_M (\|dh \|^p \circ f ) \det df \operatorname{Vol}_M. \tag{1}$$

for every $\, h \in C^{\infty}(N).$

Since $h$ can be chosen arbitrarily we hope to deduce equality of the integrands, i.e

$$ \|dh \circ df\|^p = (\|dh \|^p \circ f ) \det df \, \, \text{for every} \, h \in C^{\infty}(N). \tag{2}$$

**Is there a way to deduce this?** (from here the "pointwise question" is easy).

Selecting $h$ to be very "localized" and using a Lebesgue differentiation-type theorem seems a reasonable idea, but I could not implement this successfully. We can try selecting $h$ which are quickly decaying, and are constant outside a small set. But then at the "transition phase" their differential will have a non-negligible integral.

> Note that if we assume that $f$ restricted to arbitrarily small open subsets preserve the energy, then the proof is trivial. This is essentially an equivalent phrasing of the question: [Why are global symmetries of smooth functionals are also local symmetries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405697/are-global-symmetries-of-smooth-functionals-local)